# Увеличение размера файла *.mdb

Tags: access, delphi

Выполняю следующие действия:

1. Создаю БД *.mdb в MS Access;
2. В Delphi программно очищаю её запросом DELETE FROM MyTable;
3. В Delphi программно добавляю N записей INSERT'ом;

После этого размер БД ~400 Кб.
Повторяю шаги 2,3 (**те же записи в том же количестве**) — уже 700 Кб.
После пятой-шестой итерации размер доходит до 4,5 Мб (!) и дальше почти не растёт. Кажется, что записи на втором шаге не удаляются, но нет, смотрел БД в Access'е — после шага (2) база пуста.

Вопросов два:

1. Почему так происходит?
2. Как с этим бороться?

*P.S. Работаю через ADOCommand*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При удалении записи не физически удаляются с диска, а помечаются как удаленные. В postgresql и sqlite для этого есть SQL команда VACUUM.

Comment: Спасибо, с вопросом #1 теперь всё понятно. Вопрос #2 пока открыт.

Comment: Вариант решения через Access:
Сервис > Служебные программы > Сжать и восстановить базу данных...

Но это руками, а хочется программно.

Answer (score 3):

SQL-запросов для этого нет. Программно - создать объект Access.Application и вызвать у него метод CompactRepair